# How to access a local ressource in an aspx file

Tags: c#, asp.net, globalization

I'm a bit new to aspx (I have mostly don MVC in the past)and this may sound silly to most people, but I'm a bit stuck:
I have a page, New.aspx located in a subfolder (Incident/New.aspx) and I need the access to a resource file for globalisation purpose. So I have created a New.aspx.resx file in the App_LocalResources folder but it pops me an resource file not found when I call `GetLocalResourceObject(mykey)` in the page codebehind.

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to get global resource data using this method.

```
globalresourcestring = (String)GetGlobalResourceObject("New.aspx.resx", "Key");
```